# Adding objects to a list then print the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create objects and put each object created during the same "session" in a list and then print the list. However I get this: `[<dag.dag object at 0x0000000003156518>]` when I try to print it.

Looping through the whole list element by element works but not just printing the whole list?

```
def Create_And_Return_Object(day,list_of_temperatures):
    objekt = dag(day,list_of_temperatures) (imported class from another file)
    return objekt



def Return_List_Of_Objects(objekt):
    list_of_objects = []
    list_of_objects.append(objekt)
    return list_of_objects


def main()    
    Objekt = Create_And_Return_Object(day,list_of_temperatures)

    Objekt_list = Return_List_Of_Objects(objekt)
    print(Objekt_list)
```

When I print `Objekt_list` I get this:

```
[<dag.dag object at 0x0000000003156518>]
```

So the first function is supposed to create and return 1 object, which it does.

But the second one is supposed to put this object from function number 1 into a list and then print the whole list. But it just won't!

Comment: What's the problem? When you print `Objekt_list`, it prints the whole one element list, just as you say it should.

Answer (score 1):

The function `Return_List_Of_Objects` *does exactly what you ask it to* - it creates a list, puts the `objekt` into it and returns it. You get back a list with one `dag.dag` object in, which is then printed.

However, your `dag.dag` object apparently doesn't implement either [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) or [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), the [representation "magic methods"](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#representations) that tell Python how to display the instance e.g. when printed. You need to update the class to implement these methods, then you will see something more useful when you print the list.

For example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.day) # or whatever attribute(s) seem appropriate
```

**Note**: Python will use `__repr__` for display within a container, so if you only implement one, make it that one!

Comment: To be clear, implementing only `__str__` won't change how the object is displayed within a container. You've got to do `__repr__`, at a minimum.

Comment: That is correct, I will make that clearer